Logic port AND issue with Spice
I need to create two pwm waves with dead time on PSpice for TI.
To do this I opened the LMG5200 file of TINA where it is already done:


The problem is that I have to use PSpice for TI (for a serious of reasons), so I redesigned the circuit:


In theory, these two PSpice for TI  outputs should be the same as those obtained with TINA (i.e., two PWM waves with dead time) .. but they are not.
At the inputs of the AND there are the same signals on both PSpice and TINA, I have already checked ... so I suppose it is an AND logic port problem.
In TINA an "if" block is used, in PSpice for TI I used a comparator, making sure the output is the same for both circuits
(I also tried using NAND + NOT but nothing changes).
I have no idea what the issue might be and I don't have much experience with simulators.
What could be the problem?
Unfortunately, I cannot write on the TI forum because because they do not accept subscriptions to their forum from certain emails.
If there is missing information I can write it down, otherwise I will attach the two projects/files in case you want to check:
https://file.io/TWvEq7hLEXT3

I’m failing to understand what exactly your issue is with the PSpice simulation. Can you please clarify it?

@SteKulov In theory, the two PSpice for TI outputs should be the same as those obtained with TINA (i.e., two PWM waves with dead time) since the two circuits are the same.. but they are not

I guess my confusion is with the PSpice plot. I don’t understand it at all or what the colors mean. Looks more like a digital logic plot than an analog scope plot. Perhaps you are simply using the wrong kind of probe???

@SteKulov Unfortunately, it's the first time I've used it too, so that's why that plot confuses me too. However, I think I solved it by re-importing the base library, I think it was corrupted..
